# How to find the $ y$ value when $ x=1$ on $r=2\theta+2cos\theta$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

**Question**

Consider the polar graph $r=2\theta+2\cos\theta$ for $0<\theta<\pi$.  On that interval, there is exactly one point on the curve with an $x$-coordinate equal to $1$.  Give the $y$-coordinate of that point accurate to three decimal places.

So I plug this into a calculator and try using the trace function and realize that It is impossible to use the trace function, I was wondering if there was any way on the calculator to do this?

Comment: $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2\arctan\dfrac yx+2\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{x^2+y^2-2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=2\arctan\dfrac yx$$

$$x=1\implies\dfrac{y^2-1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=2\arctan y$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the trace function but, from $x=r \cos \theta$ we have that $x=1$ when:
$$
(2\theta+2\cos \theta) \cos \theta=1
$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282x%2B2%20cos%20x%29%20cos%20x%3D1&wal=header) finds a solution of this equation in $0<\theta< \pi$ that is: $\theta=1.2456270775...$. Now use this value to find $y=(2\theta+2\cos \theta) \sin \theta$

Answer (score 0):

From $1 = x = r \cos \theta = (2 \theta + 2 \cos\theta) \cos\theta $ find numerically

$$ \begin{cases} 
 \theta & = -4.60608105432367 \\
 \theta & = -1.81609268044352 \\
 \theta & = 1.24562707756920 \\
 \theta & = 4.81427421305973
\end{cases} $$

Then $y = (2\theta +2 \cos \theta) \sin \theta $

Comment: There are also solutions every approximately $\pi$